# Tip calculator returns zeros

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble running the code I wrote.

```
meal = float(raw_input("How much did your meal cost? "))

tax = 6.75 / 100
tip = 15 / 100

total = (meal * tax) * tip

print total
```

You can see above that I made this "tip calculator". Whenever I enter a number, it returns with zeros. It seems like it's skipping the entire calculation part.

Any solution?

Comment: do `tip = 15.0 / 100` instead of `tip = 15 / 100`

Comment: `total=meal + (meal * tax) + meal * tip` for the actual total

Answer (score 3):

If it is python 2.7 you are doing integer division, which means your tip is calculating as 15/100 = 0.

```
from __future__ import division
```

At the the top of the program will solve this.

Answer (score 1):

In python 2, `/` is integer division. Thus, 15 / 100 = 0, and you miltiply by that. Just replace 15 with 15.0

Comment: That's not quite true. In Python 2, `/` performs integer division if (& only if) both of its operands are integers (unless you do `from __future__ import division`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this line:

`tip = 15 / 100`

Dividing an `int` by an `int` will result in an `int`. In this case `15 / 100` gives you `0`, and the complementary modulo operation `15 % 100` gives the `15` remainder.

If you change `15` to a `float` it will work because precision is preserved and `tip` will be a `float` instead of an `int`. Try:

`tip = 15.0 / 100`